# Meta-analysis question

Tags: meta-analysis

How do I interpret a cumulative analysis? I understand that it is a year-wise stratification of the pooled data (and all of my studies are chronological in my forest plot), but how far of a deviation (left or right) constitutes as significant? And what does this mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a cumulative analysis. Can you post an example, or give more details?

Comment: Sure, a good example is seen here http://asq.org/quality-progress/2005/04/statistics-roundtable/cumulative-meta-analysis.html. I am using the software comprehensive meta-analysis and they have a function for this (see page 371 in Borenstein M, Hedges LV, Higgins JP, Rothstein HR. Introduction to meta-analysis. John Wiley & Sons; 2011 Aug 24.)

Answer (score 1):

Historically there was interest in cumulative approaches because enthusiasts for meta-analysis wished to point out that many successful treatments for health conditions could have been put into practice much earlier if people had kept meta-analysing as studies came in and stopped when the summary with its confidence interval was well clear of the null. The paper by Lau and colleagues entitled ["Cumulative meta-analysis of therapeutic trials for myocardial infarction"](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199207233270406) is one often cited example. In modern times the idea has been taken up by Wetterslev and colleagues in a paper entitled ["Trial sequential analysis may establish when firm evidence is reached in cumulative meta--analysis"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0895435607001473) which has been used occasionally since then. Whether this new technique is in fact the answer to the problem is, I think, still up for discussion in the community but their paper should help with your problem.